# Tables and Figures towards the end

Tags: tables, floats, positioning

I'm submitting a manuscript and the editing team asked for the following two changes:

2)  Please remove the figures from the main text file as they are already uploaded separately in the Figures section. Figure legends, however, must be included in the main manuscript text file at the end of the document (after references), rather than being a part of the figure file. For each figure, the following information should be provided: Figure number (in sequence, using Arabic numerals - i.e. Figure 1, 2, 3 etc); short title of figure (maximum 15 words); detailed legend, up to 300 words.
Please note that it is the responsibility of the author(s) to obtain permission from the copyright holder to reproduce figures or tables that have previously been published elsewhere.

3) Tables: please place your tables after the figure legends and references.

Is there an easy command that I can set both of these up?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at endfloat. http://www.ctan.org/pkg/endfloat

Comment: If you are willing to change the syntax on your figures from an environment to a macro form, the `boxhandler` package also provides deferred figures and tables.

Comment: @onewhaleid using the endfloat package is there a way to hide the actual figures?

Comment: @user1357015 they are sent the the back of the document. You could remove them by trimming those pages off your pdf after it is created.